# How to catch a number of tweets from TwitterStream by a given district of GeoLocations in twitter4j?

Tags: geolocation, twitter4j, geo

I need to catch a number of tweets from `TwitterStream`  (Because I'm doing the data mining, the number of tweets might be large)

Now I already have a list of lat/long data and I want to catch all the `tweets` by a given radius of the those lat/long

Is there a good method or class in Twitter4J to achieve this task?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answer!
Now, I found the way to deal with this question:

Here is the source code (hope this can help others)

```
FilterQuery fq = new FilterQuery();
fq.language(new String[] { "en" });
fq.locations(new double[][] { {0,10}, { 100 ,50.3 }});

twitterStream.addListener(listener);
twitterStream.filter(fq);
```

from those code, tweet inside the rectangle (0,10), (100, 50.3) will be caught